# How to get the Width/Height of a collapsed control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

im wondering if theres an easy way to get the width of a control in WPF at runtime while the control is collapsed.

when i use control.Width ill get the following result: -1.#IND
and control.actualWidth will return 0.0 because its collapsed.

i want to resize my window and then display the collapsed control.

thanks

Edit:
Some details

**i have a grid with 2 columns in my window, the 1st column holds a tab control, the 2nd column holds an expander control. i want to extend the width of my window when expanding the expander control, so the content in the 1st column will remain its size.**

Comment: Why does it have to be done this way?  Can't you just display the control then resize it?

Comment: I don't really know WPF but can you set the visibility to false and then expand it and take the width/height?

Comment: @SimonBesner i thought about doing it this way, but for me its more a workaround and not the "right" way ;) and this approach has a downside: 
lets say i have an expander control and on the expanded event ill  display the grid and resize the window directly after that. the windowsize wont change the first time im doing this. i dont know why its that way but i tested it.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion the SizeTocontent should be set to WidthAndHeight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What size do you expect to get?

The size is not just dependent on the control but also on its container. So the actual size can not be determined unless the control is actually rendered.

Instead of using Collapsed you could make it Invisible that way it will be sized by its own logic and the logic of the container.

**EDIT**

In the comments it became clear that what the reason was for needing the size of the control:

> I have a grid with 2 columns in my
>   window, the 1st column holds a tab
>   control, the 2nd column a holds an
>   expander control. i want to extend the
>   width of my window when expanding the
>   expander control, so the content in
>   the 1st column will remain its size.

My answer:

Set the SizeToContent of the window to WidthAndHeight and set the width of both grid columns to auto. That should take care of it.

Comment: when hiding the control, it will reserve its space in layout. thats why im collapsing it.

Comment: i dont know :( i thought there might be a way to get the estimated size. so i guess i can only use workarounds like displaying the control once and save the size in a variable or have the control expanded/visible by default.

Comment: Even when you call the method GetDesiredSize http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433806.aspx many times it will not be able to tell the exact size as the parent determines the actual size. You could quickly show it and hide it again. BTW: what are you trying to do? Perhaps you are approaching it from the wrong angle.

Comment: i have a grid with 2 columns in my window, the 1st column holds a tab control, the 2nd column a holds an expander control. i want to extend the width of my window when expanding the expander control, so the content in the 1st column will remain its size.

Comment: Set the SizeToContent of the window to True and set the width of both grid columns to auto. That should take care of it.

Comment: You're right. Setting the SizeToContent did the trick. should've told u guys what im trying to achieve in the first place. thanks

Comment: No problem. I'll add this solution to my answer because digging in the comments is not much fun for others. Perhaps you should add the actual question to your question too.

Answer (score 3):

Put the control in question inside a container (like a `ContentControl`) and collapse the container rather than the control itself. Then you should be able to simply call `Measure` (or use the `DesiredSize` property) on the control to determine how much room it wants.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going about this the wrong way. You can set the Window Width and height to `"Auto"` and then it will take care of all the resizing stuff.

The problem arises whenever you directly set the Width property of any control(trust me I've done it). Once you do that, you've told WPF **hands off of resizing logic, I know what I'm doing.**

If you think something isn't resizing at the right time you can add a handler to some event and then call [`control.InvalidateVisual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) or [`control.InvalidateMeasurement()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatemeasure.aspx) which will make it go through a whole new layout pass.

Comment: To set the height and width of a window to auto: set the SizeToContent of the window to True

Comment: @Erno good point, you not only have to set Width and Height to `"Auto"` but also `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `UpdateLayout` method on the control or conainer of control. After that the things may work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In UWP you can determine size of collapsed control by making it visible for a sec and then hiding it again, change is not noticeable:

```
var oldVisibility = myBorder.Visibility;
myBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
myBorder.UpdateLayout();
var height = myBorder.RenderSize.Height;
myBorder.Visibility = oldVisibility;
```

Answer (score 0):

Post which is marked as an answer actually does not answer the question, it just gives a workaround.

To get the size of the collapsed control you need:

1. Set control's visibility as Hidden (Collapsed won't evaluate).
2. Call Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity)) method of the control.
3. Get the size from DesiredSize property of the control.
4. Then you can Collapse your control back.