# window resizing on expanding a control

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

derived from the solution of my original problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707143/how-to-get-the-width-height-of-a-collapsed-control-in-wpf)

i have now the following xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="450" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="200" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />       
        <Expander Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ExpandDirection="Right">
            <StackPanel x:Name="cont">
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
                <Label>testtesttesttesttest</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

i want to extend the window width everytime i expand the expander control to the right.
when i run the above quoted xaml and expand the expander control after the build, everything works like expected, but as soon as i manually resize the window, the content of the expander control will expand into the existing area to the left.

how can i change this behaviour, so that the window will extend its width to the right side and the  content will end up in that new area?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. With the above code, the Expander will only take as much space as needed to display it's content. If you size the window horizontally, the Expander's width remains fixed and the TabControl will grow/shrink. Are you looking to have the Expander's width grow/shrink as you size the window?

Comment: @CodeNaked i want The Expander to Be only As Wide As its content(when expanded), And always aligned to The right Side. But The Size of my First Grid column should Not Change when expanding The Expander. The Window width should increase And The expanded content displayed there. I Hope its clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that is built into WPF, so you'd have to write some custom code to handle it. The SizeToContent works until the end-user resizes the window, then the Window size is fixed.

You can use something like this to accomplish what you want:

```
public partial class MainWindow  {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.WindowProc));
    }

    private const int WM_SIZING = 0x0214;
    private const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232;
    private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
        switch (msg) {
            case WM_SIZING:
                this.firstColumn.ClearValue(ColumnDefinition.MinWidthProperty);
                break;
            case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE:
                this.firstColumn.MinWidth = this.firstColumn.ActualWidth;
                this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                break;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

}
```

Then you'd need to give your first ColumnDefinition the name "firstColumn", like so:

```
<ColumnDefinition x:Name="firstColumn" Width="*" />
```

So effectively, it uses SizeToContent like you have. If you resize the window, then it ensures the first column's minimum size keeps the size fixed and toggles the SizeToContent back on.

EDIT:

Noticed you used the VB.NET tag, so here is the VB.NET version:

```
Public Partial Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSourceInitialized(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnSourceInitialized(e)

        Dim handle As IntPtr = New WindowInteropHelper(Me).Handle
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(New HwndSourceHook(AddressOf Me.WindowProc))
    End Sub

    Private Const WM_SIZING As Integer = &H214
    Private Const WM_EXITSIZEMOVE As Integer = &H232
    Private Function WindowProc(hwnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr, ByRef handled As Boolean) As IntPtr
        Select Case msg
            Case WM_SIZING
                Me.firstColumn.ClearValue(ColumnDefinition.MinWidthProperty)
                Exit Select
            Case WM_EXITSIZEMOVE
                Me.firstColumn.MinWidth = Me.firstColumn.ActualWidth
                Me.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
                Exit Select
        End Select

        Return IntPtr.Zero
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: thank you! that is what i was looking for. except for one thing:

after expanding the control and manually resizing the window, the window will automatically resize back to the contentsize when moving the window. how can i prevent that?

Comment: @r1cki - Updated to WM_SIZING, instead of WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE.